# Create a javascript function to hide elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

On a click event, the page loads the game board and several elements are hidden / shown.

Instead of having this giant thing mixed in the function:

```
$('.playervscomputer').css('display', 'block');
$('.player_vs_cpu_board').css('display', 'block');
$('.player_vs_computer_color_selection').css('display', 'block');
$('.player_vs_computer_start_button').css('display', 'block');
$('.header').css('display', 'block');
$('.hide_answer').css('display', 'block');
$('.intro').remove();
$('.player_board_header').css('display', 'inline');
$('.intro').css('padding-top', 'none');
$('#show_after_starting').css('display', 'inline');
$('#mastermind_table_ten_cpu').css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to wrap this up in its own function and just call the function when the click event occurs? I tried this, but it was unsuccessful (I'm assuming I did this wrong...)

Thanks

Comment: Whats stopping you from writing this in a function? Or is it re-use you are trying to achieve? Whats the specific use-case?

Comment: Please add your html code also.

Comment: What do you want to do? Hide couple of elements and show some others?

Comment: Thanks guys. Deepsty's solution was what I was looking for. Appreciate the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just list them with commas like this:

```
$('.playervscomputer, .player_vs_cpu_board, .player_vs_computer_color_selection, .player_vs_computer_start_button, .header, .hide_answer').css('display', 'block');
$('.intro').remove();
$('.player_board_header, #show_after_starting').css('display', 'inline');
$('.intro').css('padding-top', 'none');
$('#mastermind_table_ten_cpu').css('background-color', 'yellow')
```

**EDIT:** Although in my opinion the best approach will be if u make a css class like this:

```
.dblock .playervscomputer,.dblock .player_vs_cpu_board, .dblock .player_vs_computer_color_selection, .dblock .player_vs_computer_start_button, .dblock .header, .dblock .hide_answer 
{
 display: block;
}
```

and just do `$("parent-selector").addClass("dblock")` to the parent element of all these boxes. This will be the fastest and cleanest approach. Also jQuery queries are expensive. Don't overuse them.

Comment: @user3007294 I edited my post and added a CSS solution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I agree the css class looks a bit cleaner (both look much better than what I had).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can chain things like  ,And call this function on ready

```
function init() {
    $('.playervscomputer , .player_vs_cpu_board').css('display', 'block');

} 

$(document).ready(function() {
init();

});
```